# Trouble setting up linprog in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am using the following code but I have not been able to set up the problem to run.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

c = np.asarray([-0.098782540360068297, -0.072316526358138802, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004])
A_ub = np.asarray([[1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [-1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1.0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
b_ub = np.asarray([3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 20.0])
A_eq = np.asarray([[1.0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1], [0, -1.0, -1, 1, -1, 1]])
b_eq = np.asarray([0,0])
res = linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq)
lb = np.zeros([6,1]) #lower bound for x array
ub = np.ones([6,1])*2 #upper bound for x array
res2 = linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, bounds=(lb, ub))
```

I get error as:

```
ValueError: Invalid input for linprog with method = 'simplex'.  Length of bounds is inconsistent with the length of c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounds parameter wants a list of pairs. Use something like:

```
lb = np.zeros(6) #lower bound for x array
ub = np.ones(6)*2 #upper bound for x array
res2 = linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, bounds=list(zip(lb, ub)))
```